# Why/How does this extension function work? How to call it without `with`?

Tags: kotlin

While taking the ["Kotlin for Java Developers" Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/kotlin-for-java-developers/) course, I came across this construction, where an extension function for a contained instance seems to have access to the containing class' private fields. Note how the `Data` class is implemented outside of `Container` and does not have access to `Container`'s fields, but the `Data.printMe()` extension function *can* access `Container`'s private `containerVal` member:

```kotlin
data class Data (val data: String)

class Container (private val containerVal: String, val data: Data){
    fun Data.printMe() {
        println("data: $data - in container: ${this@Container.containerVal}")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val c = Container("mycontainer", Data("mydata"))
    // Can I call Data.printMe without using `with`?
    // val d = c.data.printMe();
    with (c) {
        // Prints: data: mydata - in container: mycontainer
        data.printMe();
    }
}
```

Pretty cool that `Data.printMe` can access `Container`'s private members. The `with(c)` is apparently what allows that. I can see lots of use cases for this, just like how in the course example extension functions for a game's `Cell`s can access the containing `Board` without the `Cell` class itself being polluted by and tightly coupled with `Board`.

Does this "approach" have a name? And is there a syntax to call `c.data.printMe` "directly" without using `with`? The [with documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#with) doesn't mention this use case.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printMe()` method has two receivers: the *dispatch receiver* and the *extension receiver*. The *dispatch receiver* is the instance of the class in which the extension is declared, and the *extension receiver* is the instance of the receiver type of the extension method. You are accessing `contaiverVal` in the context of a `Container` instance (dispatch receiver), not a `Data` instance (extension receiver).

If you try to do the opposite and access a private property of the `Data` class inside the `printMe()`, you will get a compiler error.

when you define an extension function as a member of a class, it is only usable in the context that class. You can access it inside the class or using a scope function where the context object is available as a lambda receiver (this). Those functions are `run`, `with` and `apply`.